# Nlog.web не работают дополнительные layout renderers

Tags: логирование, asp.net-web-api, nlog

Использую фреймворк webapi 2.1 .Net framework.
Для логирования приложения используется Nlog, с кастомным таргетом для graylog.
Добавляю дополнительные параметры для отображения в логах из пакета nlog.web.

```
<parameter name="exception_type" layout="${exception:format=Type}" />
<parameter name="method" layout="${aspnet-Request-Method} ${aspnet-Request-Url}" />
<parameter name="site" layout="${iis-site-name} ${aspnet-appbasepath}" />
```

*Первый параметр встроен в Nlog и отображается в логах*.
**Остальные 2 из nlog.web не отображаются**, в офф. референсе описано, что пакету nlog.web ничего не надо, только подключить.

Comment: а почему заглавная буква в Request? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetRequest-Method-Layout-Renderer

Comment: проблема решилась переустановкой пакета nlog.web